# How to define a mapping function for GADT in OCaml?

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, ocaml, generic-programming, gadt

I'm trying to study the possibilities of GADTs in OCaml language and define as strong as possible what exactly a mapping function should do with such types. Unfortunately, I did not manage to finish the definition of the mapping function for a type in the example below. The full text of this example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ramntry/68a7534d88f4a40e28b2). I would be grateful for any help in this matter. Thank you all.

```ml
type ('a, _) expr =
  | Const : 'a -> ('a, 'a) expr
  | Add : ('a, 'a) expr * ('a, 'a) expr -> ('a, 'a) expr
  | Less : ('a, 'a) expr * ('a, 'a) expr -> ('a, bool) expr
  | Not : ('a, bool) expr -> ('a, bool) expr
  | If : ('a, bool) expr * ('a, 'a) expr * ('a, 'a) expr -> ('a, 'a) expr
```